# Is to possible to serve a PHP application locally in an Android app?

Tags: php, android

I have created a web application and I want to serve my PHP web site on the local device. I've already connected my site to a sqlite database on my computer which can run PHP. So is there any way for installing my app acting as a kind of php server on an android device?

Comment: Please post the actual code, not an image of the code.

Comment: Try Palapa WebServer if you want to run PHP scripts on your android device

Comment: I dont need to show the code. I just want to know if there is a way for executing php in localhost ( android device). Also if there any way for installing my app and some php server at the same? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run PHP on your local device, first of all install one of web servers with PHP from google play:

```
Ulti Server: PHP, MySQL, PMA (Tested)
KSWEB: server + PHP + MySQL
PAW Server for Android
Bit Web Server (PHP,MySQL,PMA)
AndroPHP
Palapa Web Server
```

You can read more on this topic here: https://androidwebdev.wordpress.com/how-to-run-php-code/